# How to parse this sentence?これらはヘッジファンドを自分のリソースとは無関係の投資先とみなすことのリスク管理上の問題点を浮き彫りにしている。

Tags: translation, meaning

How would I parse this sentence into smaller and more understandable bits?

> これらはヘッジファンドを自分のリソースとは無関係の投資先とみなすことのリスク管理上の問題点を浮き彫りにしている。

Answer (score 4):

I would parse it as...

> これらは｛（ヘッジファンドを自分のリソースとは無関係の投資先とみなすことの）（リスク管理上の）問題点を｝浮き彫りにしている

これらは -- subject
問題点を -- object
浮き彫りにしている -- verb

Both 「ヘッジファンドを自分のリソースとは無関係の投資先とみなすことの」 and 「リスク管理上の」 modify 問題点.

---

ヘッジファンドを自分のリソースとは無関係の投資先とみなすこと is a noun clause.

> ｛ヘッジファンドを｝｛（自分のリソースとは無関係の）投資先と｝みなす

ヘッジファンドを is the object of the verb みなす. ("regard/see/consider ヘッジファンド as 自分のリソースとは無関係の投資先"). 自分のリソースとは無関係の modifies 投資先.

Comment: So would the translation be something like: "These (examples) brings to light the risk management issue of viewing a hedgefund as an investment separate from your own resources"?

Comment: @Ciaran Yes, I think it's something like that.. Anyway I think it's basically saying "These (examples) clearly show that it's problematic/dangerous to think that hedge fund is unrelated to your resource / think that hedge fund has nothing to do with your resource."